# jquery функция внутри блока

Tags: jquery, frontend

```js
$('.show-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.hidden-item').css('display', 'block');
  $('.show-link').css('display', 'none');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filter-wrap">

  <label class="radio">
        <input type="checkbox" name="price">
        <div class="radio__text">Альостромерии</div>
    </label>

  <div class="show-link">Показать все</div>

  <label class="radio hidden-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="price">
        <div class="radio__text">Орхидея</div>
    </label>
  <label class="radio hidden-item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="price">
        <div class="radio__text">Подсолнух</div>
    </label>

</div>
```

Eсть несколько блоков `class="show-link"`, как сделать чтобы функция выполнялась внутри блока по которому кликнули?

Answer (score 1):

Как понимаю, вы хотите воздействовать на элементы, которые находятся внутри блока по которому кликают.
Но тогда не понимаю, зачем прятать данный блок.
Покажите хотя бы кусок html кода.
чтобы выбрать элемент внутри блока, по которому кликнули:

```
$('.show-link').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Выбираем .hidden-item внутри this
  $('.hidden-item', this).css('display', 'block');
  return !1;
});
```

Comment: `return !1;` - *Они образованность показать хочут*?

Comment: .show-link это кнопка "показать все" и после ее нажатия она пропадает а появляется .hidden-item

Comment: @Igor ну если вы не знаете, то это дело лично ваше. А для меня - привычка.

Comment: @Linkin
Тогда вам проще использовать parent()   
`$('.show-link').on('click', function(e) {   
  e.preventDefault();   
  // Выбираем .hidden-item внутри родителя, в котором находится this   
  $('.hidden-item', $(this).parent()).show();   
  $(this).hide();   
  return !1;   
});`

Comment: Спасибо именно то что искал!

Answer (score 0):

Как `'.show-link'` соотносится с `'.hidden-item'`?

```
$('.show-link').on('click', function() {
  $('.hidden-item').show();
  $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция не может выполняться "внутри блока", то, что ты называешь блоком - это DOM элемент, и "внутри него" функции не выполняются. Однако, если ты делаешь

```
$('.element').on('click', function(event){
   // this будет ссылаться на ДОМ-элемент, на который ты вешаешь обработчик.
})
```